# Symfony 2: __construct missing 2 params

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:
Warning: Missing argument 2 for Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica::__construct
(), called in C:\wamp\www\galileo\src\Agc\ManagerBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 101
 and defined in C:\wamp\www\galileo\src\Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica.php line 10
```

My class `grafica`:

```
class grafica
{
    protected $conn;

    protected $bdnmgi;

    function __construct($conn, $esq)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
        $this->bdnmgi = $esq;
    }
```

My call to new object grafica from `DefaultController`:

```
$grafica = new grafica($this->get('database_connection'), $esquema);
```

The problem is that when I try create a new `grafica` instance, the constructor does not recognize my var `$esquema`. Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you.

---

Ok, Here are the above lines to the creation of graphic:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboardAction(Request $peticion)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer_1');
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $esquema = $user->getAdministracion()->getNombreEsquemamgi();
        var_dump($esquema);
        $grafica = new grafica($this->get('database_connection'), $esquema)
```

;

Comment: Could you var_dump $esquema to see if it's define/what is inside ?

Comment: Yes, i had var_dump $esquema, this var return string "tecnitax" for example

Comment: Triple check you don't have a typo of some kind.  Maybe paste a few more lines from your controller from before the new statement.

Comment: Ok, Here are the above lines to the creation of graphic: